# JDBC Prepared Statement, compiler doesn't recogonise set methods

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to set the variables in a prepared statement as follows:

```
String addRow = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(?,?,?)";
Statement preparedStat = connection.prepareStatement(addRow);
preparedStat.setClob(1,myClob);
```

however I get a "cannot find symbol" error for the method setClob. I get the same error if I try to use any of the set methods, e.g. setInt etc. I have imported the sql library:

```
import java.sql.*;
```

Any idea why my compiler isn't recognising any of the set methods here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setClob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setClob%28int,%20java.sql.Clob%29) method belongs to [PreparedStatment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) class but your reference is of [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) class and `Statement` class does not have any method called `setClob`. Hence it throws the error. Update your declaration from

```
Statement preparedStat = connection.prepareStatement(addRow);
```

to

```
PreparedStatement preparedStat = connection.prepareStatement(addRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here preparedstat object is  of type statement,so statement interface does not contain setXXX() methods to set the values.
Preparedstatement interface having setXXX() methods to set values.so that you can use Preparedstatement to insert values into table instead of statement interface.

PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
pastmt.setXXX();

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
PreparedStatement preparedStat;
```

[`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) doesn't declare that method

Answer (score 0):

change statement to PreparedStatement;

```
PreparedStatement preparedStat = connection.prepareStatement(addRow);
```